# Is the CR for the Kuo-Toa Whip accurate?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, cr-calculation, errata

In the Monster's Manual, the Kuo-Toa Whip has a CR of 1, but that seems much too low given that it has 10d8+20 hit dice (average of 65 hp) and 2nd level spellcasting abilities. This seems to be more in line with a CR of 3, like the variant Kuo-toa Monitor which has the same stats, merely swapping the spellcasting out for a multi attack.

There's no mention of this in the [Monster Manual errata from 2016 (pdf)](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/MM_Errata.pdf).

Am I right that a CR of 3 is probably more accurate for this monster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It wasn't in the errata, so yes it is accurate.

Lacking any corrections from the game designers themselves, CR1 is the correct CR for the Kuo-toa Whip.

You can reconstruct the creature's CR using the rules in Creating a Monster in the DMG page 273.

Using those rules, we get that the Whip has a Defensive CR of 1/4 (1/2 if we assume it always has Shield of Faith on), and an Offensive CR of 1. Its spellcasting doesn't really matter for Offensive CR as it has little damaging spells. So it should really only be CR 1/2.

But a critical thing you're missing is that the ultimate Challenge Rating for a monster isn't derived from crunching numbers, but rather through playtesting again and again.

> Creating a monster isn't just a number-crunching exercise. The guidelines in this chapter can help you create monsters, but the only way to know whether a monster is fun is to playtest it. **After seeing your monster in action, you might want to adjust the challenge rating up or down based on your experiences**.
>
> (DMG 275)

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I should ask then if people's experience using this particular monster line up with the CR of 1. Looking at it more, the only real issue I see is the abnormally high hp.

Comment: Might be worth pointing out that the AC is 11 making it incredibly easy to hit, and it's spells are not offensive in nature, as well as sunlight sensitivity setting it at disadvantage. The CR 1 is likely due to it being a support role rather than a frontliner, and is coupled with the sheer weight of how easy it would be to take on.

Comment: AC 11 if Shield of Faith isnt on, with its spell list, its unlikely. So I assumed it's 13